# How to mpf an array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, mpf, mpmath

I have:

```
import numpy as np
from mpmath import *

mpf(np.array(range(0,600)))
```

But it won't let me do it:

```
TypeError: cannot create mpf from array
```

So what should I be doing?

Essentially I'm going to have use this array and multiply element-wise with an incredibly large or incredible small number depending on circumstance (eg `1.35626567e1084` or `6.2345252e-2732`) hence the need for mpf.

More specifically I'll be using the besseli and besselk function which create the incredible large and incredible small values.

How do I get an mpf array to hold these numbers?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Multiplying an array by a mpf number just works:

```
import numpy as np
import mpmath as mp
small_number = mp.besseli(400, 2)  # This is an mpf number
# Note that creating a list using `range` and then converting it
# to an array is not very efficient. Do this instead:
A = np.arange(600)
result = small_number * A  # Array of dtype object, ie, it contains mpf numbeers
```

Multiplying element-wise two arrays containing mpf numbers also works:

```
result * result
```

So your real problem is how to evaluate an mpmath function in a numpy array. To do that, I'd use [`np.frompyfunc`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.frompyfunc.html) (some time ago this was the only option).

```
besseli_vec = np.frompyfunc(mp.besseli, 2, 1)
besseli_vec(0, A)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I was just about to give up and use sluggish for loops! You mention this was the only option some time ago, what are the other options nowadays?

Comment: @Rapid A quick google search seems to imply that it's still the only way. That's understandable since this option is so simple.

Comment: I am having same issue in a different setting and I just linked my post to this page. Would appreciate any help,

Comment: So when I have to multiply a np.array I happen to have by some mpf number there is no point in first converting the np.array to mpf and then multiplying it with the mpf number? The result will be the same (same accuracy) as directly performing the multiplication?

Answer (score 3):

Check out [`mpmath.arange`](http://mpmath.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/build/general.html?highlight=range#mpmath.arange):

```
import numpy as np
import mpmath as mp

np.array(mp.arange(600))
```

Comment: I still can't do this `A=np.array(arange(600))` followed by `besseli(0,A)` without it throwing errors at me?