# Create mpf from array

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, mpmath

I'm trying to use `fsolve` in combination with the `mpmath` package.
However, I get the error `cannot create mpf from array([mpf('1.0')], dtype=object)`.

Here is a minimal example reproducing the error. For this example, I technically do not need the `mpmath` package, but my actual function contains hyperconfluent functions that do.

```
from scipy.optimize import fsolve
#from mpmath import hyp1f1 as hyp1f1mp
#from mpmath import gamma as gammamp
import mpmath as mp
#import numpy as np

mp.dps = 250; mp.pretty = True


def cosFunc(p):
   vn = p
   output = mp.sin(vn)
   return output

estimate = mp.mpf(1)
value = fsolve(cosFunc,estimate)
print value
```

I found a similar question suggesting to use `np.frompyfunc` ([How to mpf an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13743785/how-to-mpf-an-array)), but it tells me that the function is not callable (when I apply it on `vn`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trick is to apply `np.frompyfunc` to a function instead of a value. I think the following modification would make your function work:

```
def cosFunc(p):
  vn = p
  np_sin = np.frompyfunc(mp.sin, 1, 1)
  output = np_sin(vn)
  return float(output)

value = fsolve(cosFunc, 1)
print value
```

Answer (score 1):

The specific cause of the error you is this:

```
(Pdb) x0
array([mpf('1.0')], dtype=object)
(Pdb) mp.sin(x0)
*** TypeError: cannot create mpf from array([mpf('1.0')], dtype=object)
```

What happens is that `fsolve` tries to convert your `estimate` to array and numpy does not know how to handle mpmath objects.

```
>>> np.asarray(mp.mpf(1))
>>> array(mpf('1.0'), dtype=object)
```

Changing how `fsolve` works is not very productive, so your best bet seems to be to teach your function to handle arrays of mpmath objects

```
def cos_func(p):
   vn = p
   if isinstance(p, np.ndarray):
         if p.size == 0: 
             vn = p[0]
         else:
             raise ValueError  # or whatever you want to do here"
   return mp.sin(vn)
```

Comment: Hi. I quickly tried your function definition, but it's still not working. I'm pretty busy on another project right now, but I'll come back to this soon and keep you posted. Thanks.