# How to manage "TypeError" message when plotting functions defined in mpmath module instead of scipy?

Tags: arrays, numpy, matplotlib, typeerror, mpmath

For the purpose of my problem, I have to use *gamma* functions from `mpmath` module rather than *scipy*. However, I am using `matplotlib.pyplot` to plot my functions when the variable is taken from a `numpy` *array* and the y-values are supposed to be produced in the same format. But in doing so, I am receiving an error message of `TypeError` complaining of the conversion from *array* to *mpf*.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import quad, dblquad
import mpmath as mp


low, up  = 5.630e5, 1.167e12
alpha, threshold = 1.05   , 2.15e10     
beta = 274

def g(x, low, up, beta):
    return mp.gamma(-2/3) * (mp.gammainc(-2/3, beta*(x/low)**3) - mp.gammainc(-2/3, beta*(x/up)**3))

def Integrand1(x, low, up, threshold, alpha, beta):
    return pow(x/threshold, alpha) * g(x, low, up, beta)

def Integrand2(x, low, up, threshold, alpha, beta):
    return g(x, low, up, beta)


def PDF(x, low, up, threshold, alpha, beta):
    A = quad(Integrand1, low, threshold, args=(low, up, threshold, alpha, beta))
    B = quad(Integrand2, threshold, up, args=(low, up, threshold, alpha, beta))
    C=(A[0]+B[0])**(-1)
    y = np.piecewise(x, 
                    [x < threshold], [lambda x: C * pow(x/threshold, alpha) * g(x, low, up, beta), 
                                   lambda x: C *                           g(x, low, up, beta)
                                  ]
                    )
    return y


x_array = np.array(np.logspace(8.2, 11.8, 10))
y_array = PDF(x_array, low, up, threshold, alpha, beta)
plt.plot(x_array, y_array, color='green', linestyle='-')
plt.gca().autoscale(False)
plt.vlines([threshold], 
        plt.gca().get_ylim()[0], plt.gca().get_ylim()[1], 
        linestyles='dashed', color='k', label='')

plt.xscale("log", nonposx='clip')
plt.yscale("log", nonposy='clip')
plt.show()
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "test.py", line 35, in
>   
>       y_array = PDF(x_array, low, up, threshold, alpha, beta)   File "test.py", line 28, in PDF
>       lambda x: C *                           g(x, low, up, beta)   File "/home/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py",
>   line 1344, in piecewise
>       y[condlist[k]] = item(vals, *args, **kw)   File "test.py", line 27, in 
>       [x < threshold], [lambda x: C * pow(x/threshold, alpha) * g(x, low, up, beta),    File "test.py", line 13, in g
>       return mp.gamma(-2/3) * (mp.gammainc(-2/3, beta*(x/low)**3) - mp.gammainc(-2/3, beta*(x/up)**3))   File
>   "/home/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mpmath/functions/expintegrals.py",
>   line 141, in gammainc
>       a = ctx.convert(a)   File "/home/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mpmath/ctx_mp_python.py",
>   line 662, in convert
>       return ctx._convert_fallback(x, strings)   File "/home/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mpmath/ctx_mp.py",
>   line 614, in _convert_fallback
>       raise TypeError("cannot create mpf from " + repr(x)) TypeError: cannot create mpf from array([  6.11259157e+09,   9.68780477e+10,
>   1.53541358e+12,
>            2.43346654e+13,   3.85678455e+14,   6.11259157e+15])

I need to know how to mpf an array and I found thes pages ([How to mpf an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13743785/how-to-mpf-an-array)) and ([create an mpf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36429875/create-mpf-from-array?noredirect=1&lq=1)) but I don't know how to apply them to my plotting routine.

Comment: After remove the function *g* and replacing it simply with unity, the code works. So obviously, something has to be done for the function g so that it is compatible with the other functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't about plotting. The error occurs within the function `PDF`, specifically within `np.piecewise`. As the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.piecewise.html) says, the lambdas you pass to `piecewise` must be able to take an array, because this is what `piecewise` will pass to them.

And your function `g` isn't able to take an array, because the mpmath functions it uses are meant for a single float. Solution: [`np.vectorize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html) wrapper:

```
gv = np.vectorize(g)
```

and then use `gv` instead of `g` in `piecewise`.

Then `np.piecewise` will work, and you'll be able to proceed to other errors, like mismatched names `PDF_values` and `y_array`.

Comment: @thanks. After correcting that vecorization, I am receiving this: "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'float' and 'vectorize'" in the piecewise line. All I did replaced g with gv and the statement you mentioned right after the definition of the g function.

Comment: Works on my computer: `y = np.piecewise(x, [x < threshold], [lambda x: C * pow(x/threshold, alpha) * gv(x, low, up, beta), lambda x: C *  gv(x, low, up, beta) ] )`

Comment: Explicit variables of gv were missing in the parentheses. I thought it could memorize it from the defined statement.