# curve_fit and mpmath.polylog

Tags: python, curve-fitting, mpmath

I am trying to fit (using scipy.optimize.curve_fit) using [mpmath.polylog](https://www.mpmath.org/doc/current/functions/zeta.html?highlight=polylog#mpmath.polylog).

For this I have defined the following function

```
def Vendik(x, C, T0, eps_cst, Td, xsi):
    integral = (np.pi**2)/6. + (Td/x) * np.log(1-np.cosh(Td/x)+np.sinh(Td/x)) - polylog(2, np.exp(-Td/x))
    eta = ( Td/ (2*T0) ) * ( 0.5 + 2./(Td/x)**2 * integral) -1
    term1 = np.sqrt( xsi**2 + eta**3 ) + xsi
    term2 = np.sqrt( xsi**2 + eta**3 ) - xsi 
    return eps_cst + (C*1e4/T0) / ( term1**(2./3.) + term2**(2./3.) - eta )
```

The data I want to fit are in a pandas DataFrame, and I carry out the fit with

```
xdata = data1['T(K)']
ydata = data1['epsr_STO’]
p1 = np.array([5.769, 13.16, 66.7, 86.5, 0.667])
popt_Vendik, pcov_Vendik = curve_fit(Vendik, xdata, ydata, p1)
```

This gives me an error:

```
File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mpmath/ctx_mp.py:634 in _convert_fallback
    raise TypeError("cannot create mpf from " + repr(x))
```

whereas if I try `res= [Vendik(data1['T(K)'][i], 5.769, 13.16, 66.7, 86.5, 0.667) for i in range(len(data1))]` I do not get such an error message. Therefore, the `Vendik` function works with these data. I have defined other fitting functions (not relying on `mpmath`), and the fit works seamlessly with the same data.

I have tried to transform my `xdata` and `ydata` into `np.array()` and `list` but the error message persists.
Would someone have a suggestion as to what I should modify to carry out my fit, I’d very much appreciate it.

Below are the first 100 values for `xdata=data1[’T(K)’]` and `ydata=data1[‘epsr_STO’]` respectively

```
data = [6.1727,  6.5735,  6.8074,  7.1052,  7.333,  7.6286,  7.8439,  8.1311,  8.3964,  8.6278,  8.887,  9.1358,  9.3781,  9.6301,  9.8589,  10.0725,  10.3733,  10.6386,  10.8744,  11.1192,  11.373,  11.6233,  11.8729,  12.1353,  12.3567,  12.6395,  12.8974,  13.1583,  13.4392,  13.67,  13.9283,  14.2244,  14.4684,  14.7365,  14.9683,  15.2161,  15.4826,  15.7594,  16.0293,  16.2869,  16.5325,  16.7837,  17.0395,  17.2937,  17.5569,  17.8181,  18.0474,  18.3436,  18.6019,  18.854,  19.083,  19.3497,  19.6359,  19.8911,  20.1694,  20.4052,  20.707,  20.9671,  21.2323,  21.483,  21.7547,  21.9903,  22.2897,  22.5568,  22.818,  23.0883,  23.3466,  23.6158,  23.8702,  24.1274,  24.3925,  24.6567,  24.9204,  25.1985,  25.516,  25.8149,  26.1764,  26.4486,  26.7175,  26.9845,  27.2523,  27.5219,  27.7737,  28.0813,  28.3641,  28.6534,  28.9295,  29.2104,  29.487,  29.7602,  30.0334,  30.3026,  30.5742,  30.8446,  31.1174,  31.3826,  31.6518,  31.9262,  32.1889,  32.4566]
ydata = [2326.1750294600747,  2325.5381972187943,  2324.851474894096,  2323.94171454941,  2322.861740978944,  2321.6144888934873,  2320.3466938325055,  2318.530107853923,  2316.684174767447,  2314.8910664751784,  2312.634273878199,  2310.3070482222765,  2307.8683035563604,  2305.2153250028246,  2302.5828894248134,  2299.7303505376044,  2296.4552132967347,  2293.2710520903333,  2290.2629735312908,  2287.298915634088,  2284.3465965800424,  2281.538078354673,  2278.864556825612,  2276.164622899447,  2273.4881666595966,  2270.7324732284346,  2267.6363533457125,  2263.7684045254023,  2259.1843862725004,  2254.039838258841,  2248.2584580039006,  2241.75513889479,  2234.585640436506,  2227.9385204987193,  2221.085970805681,  2213.716912013724,  2205.549611887075,  2196.3845100920607,  2187.407229787562,  2178.6177709735794,  2169.8312468703857,  2160.739512845104,  2151.4364796429923,  2141.9514943719428,  2132.117278516966,  2122.021873401741,  2111.671148447845,  2101.2646639889526,  2091.2543654866167,  2081.082657890869,  2070.488351941461,  2059.5976402023325,  2048.9710524342418,  2038.0245811901161,  2026.822790107321,  2015.6943667942583,  2004.2343211620039,  1993.1939391726203,  1982.326705119806,  1971.2481718901618,  1959.9788824592122,  1948.5159021161685,  1937.24074326364,  1925.871673665854,  1914.5701024162224,  1903.077774965285,  1891.459254950408,  1880.1077936173576,  1868.9353496424553,  1858.0798544327986,  1846.998386492365,  1835.7349664829937,  1824.4891547383586,  1813.1729099347804,  1800.4744163494368,  1787.1801764738636,  1774.0796275103846,  1762.5286058436618,  1751.781694933209,  1741.093478238543,  1730.422869808613,  1719.7845431973649,  1708.8380719532395,  1697.645085002812,  1686.114606311614,  1674.760210267774,  1663.4058142239346,  1652.2186966950858,  1641.0139709015014,  1630.038152549483,  1619.0183135356244,  1608.0454298943953,  1597.210477660264,  1586.3755254261318,  1575.6755698883085,  1564.9403978210134,  1554.307940631344,  1543.6608098877282,  1533.1926965022603,  1522.6952360088992]
```

Comment: I think this could help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51971328/how-to-evaluate-a-numpy-array-inside-an-mpmath-fuction

Comment: mpmath functions only work with scalar values, not numpy arrays.

Comment: @CarlosHorn:Thank you!. The problem is solved by defining `polylog_array = np.frompyfunc(polylog, 2, 1)` outside the `Vendik` function and replacing `integral = (np.pi**2)/6. + (Td/x) * np.log(1-np.cosh(Td/x)+np.sinh(Td/x)) - polylog(2, np.exp(-Td/x))`with `integral = (np.pi**2)/6. + (Td/x) * np.log(1-np.cosh(Td/x)+np.sinh(Td/x)) - polylog_array(2, np.exp(-Td/x))`